# MySQL receiving syntax error when creating and inserting data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I create a table

```
create table if not exists gbpExchangeRates (
    date date
    , to_currency char(3)
    , rate float
    , index idx (date, to_currency)
);
```

Then add then try to insert data

```
INSERT INTO gbpExchangeRates ('date', 'to_currency', 'rate') VALUES ('2018-01-22', 'CAD', 1.7253437447) ;
```

But I get the following error

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date', 'to_currency', 'rate') VALUES ('2018-01-22', 'CAD', 1.7253437447)' at line 1
```

I tried the following but still receiving the error message:

- `ALTER TABLE gbpExchangeRates MODIFY to_currency char(10);`
- `ALTER TABLE gbpExchangeRates MODIFY to_currency varchar(10);`
- `ALTER TABLE gbpExchangeRates MODIFY rate double;`
- `ALTER TABLE gbpExchangeRates MODIFY to_currency varchar(10);`
- `INSERT INTO gbpExchangeRates ('date', 'to_currency', 'rate') VALUES ('2018-01-22', 'CAD', 1.72) ;`
- and variations of

What is wrong with my table and/or insert statement?

Comment: You are using single quotes where you should not be.  I am voting to close as a typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO gbpExchangeRates (date, to_currency, rate) VALUES ('2018-01-22', 'CAD', 1.7253437447) ;
```

You don't need quotes for the field to insert into

Answer (score 0):

Field names are without quotes or you can use backticks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes

```
INSERT INTO gbpExchangeRates (date, to_currency, rate) VALUES
('2018-01-22', 'CAD', 1.7253437447) ;
```